# Simple HTTP Server in C - How to response to Browser?

Tags: c, http, networking, response

my server is sending a sample response header with body to a request:

```
    static char* not_found_response_template = 
      "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\n"
      "Content-type: text/html\n"
      "\n"
      "<html>\n"
      " <body>\n"
      "  <h1>Not Found</h1>\n"
      "  <p>The requested URL was not found on this server.</p>\n"
      " </body>\n"
      "</html>\n";


    len = strlen(not_found_response_template);
    send(newSct, not_found_response_template, len, 0);
```

it is sending it correctly but firefox keeps on loading until I cancel the transfer.

the firefox plugin HttpRequestHelper shows this:

GET localhost:6666

-- response --
404 Not Found
Content-Type:  text/html

why the content is not loaded?

Comment: For the http header, use \r\n line terminators.  That may not be it, but I don't see anything else wrong here and the standard mandates  CRLF terminators for the protocol traffic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try flushing and/or closing the socket after sending the response.

Comment: @XHotSniperX do a shutdown on the socket before calling close

Answer (score 5):

HTTP requires that lines be terminated by CR+LF, so try `\r\n`.

Comment: @XHotSniperX That doesn't mean you should abuse the standards.

Comment: No, it means this shouldn't be an answer, but a comment as it does not fix the problem.